# CSV cannot be interpreted by numeric values

Tags: python, pandas, csv, floating-point

(This is a mix between code and 'user' issue, but since i suspect the issue is code, i opted to post in StackOverflow instead of SuperUser Exchange).

I generated a .csv file with `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv()` method. This file consists in 2 columns: one is a label (text) and another is a numeric value called accuracy (float). The delimiter used to separate columns is comma (,) and all float values are stored with dot ponctuation like this: 0.9438245862

Even saving this column as float, Excel and Google Sheets infer its type as text. And when i try to format this column as number, they ignore "0." and return a very high value instead of decimals like:

(text) 0.9438245862       =>   (number) 9438245862,00

I double-checked my .csv file reimporting it again with `pandas.read_csv()` and printing `dataframe.dtypes` and the column is imported as float succesfully.

I'd thank for some guidance on what am i missing.

Thanks,

Comment: Usually, such issues are resolved by using a separator. I have no way to test this in your case since you have not provided a reproducible sample. Hence, I suggest you try this `df.to_csv('test.csv', sep='\t')`. Use some sort of separator by setting the 'sep' param in to_csv dunction and see if that resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By itself, the csv file should be correct. Both you and Pandas know what delimiter and floating point format are. But Excel might not agree with you, depending on your locale. A simple way to make sure is to write a tiny Excel sheet containing on first row one text value and one floating point one. You then export the file as csv and control what delimiter and floating point formats are.

AFAIK, it is much more easy to change your Python code to follow what **your** Excel expects that trying to explain Excel that the format of CSV files can vary...

---

I know that you can change the delimiter and floating point format in the current locale in a Windows system. Simply it is a *global* setting...

Comment: Thank you. What you said about testing a first line explained what was causing this error. I was exporting the csv file with the first line being column headers (text), and then all the values that should be float were inferred as text.

Answer (score 0):

A short example of data would be most useful here. Otherwise we have no idea what you're actually writing/reading. But I'll hazard a guess based on the information you've provided.

The pandas dataframe will have column names. These column names will be text. Unless you tell Excel/Sheets to use the first row as the column name, it will have to treat the column as text. If this isn't the case, could you perhaps save the head of the dataframe to a csv, check it in a text editor, and see how Excel/Sheets imports it. Then include those five rows and two columns in your follow up.

Answer (score 0):

The coding is not necessarily the issue here, but a combination of various factors.  I am assuming that your computer is not using the dot character as a decimal separator, due to your language settings (for example, French, Dutch, etc).  Instead your computer (and thus also Excel) is likely using a comma as a decimal separator.

If you want to open the data of your analysis / work later with Excel with little to no changes, you can either opt to change how Excel works or how you store the data to a CSV file.

Choosing the later, you can specify the decimal character for the [df.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) method.  It has the "decimal" keyword.  You should then also remember that you have to change the decimal character during the importing of your data (if you want to read again the data).

Continuing with the approach of adopting your Python code, you can use the following code snippets to change how you write the dataframe to a csv

```
import pandas as pd

... some transformations here ...
df.to_csv('myfile.csv', decimal=',')
```

If you, then, want to read that output file back in with Python (using Pandas), you can use the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', decimal=',')
```